# popup form appears once its submitted even after the cookies are maintained

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, cookies

I have a popup form in the home page of my website, where once i fill in that form and submit it the form is working fine, but the issue is as the page reloads again the form is back.

What actually i need is, once i submit the form it should get submitted and it should be closed and never want to popup till the sessions and cookies are cleared.

Well fine i have created the session and cookies to, but seems to have a problem still, so please do refer the code and help me solving the issue.

```js
/*
 * First Visit Popup jQuery Plugin version 1.2
 * Chris Cook - chris@chris-cook.co.uk
 */

(function ($) {

 'use strict';

 $.fn.firstVisitPopup = function (settings) {

  var $body = $('body');
  var $dialog = $(this);
  var $blackout;
  var setCookie = function (name, value) {
   var date = new Date(),
    expires = 'expires=';
   date.setTime(date.getTime() + 31536000000);
   expires += date.toGMTString();
   document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; ' + expires + '; path=/';
  }
  var getCookie = function (name) {
   var allCookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
    cookieCounter = 0,
    currentCookie = '';
   for (cookieCounter = 0; cookieCounter < allCookies.length; cookieCounter++) {
    currentCookie = allCookies[cookieCounter];
    while (currentCookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {
     currentCookie = currentCookie.substring(1, currentCookie.length);
    }
    if (currentCookie.indexOf(name + '=') === 0) {
     return currentCookie.substring(name.length + 1, currentCookie.length);
    }
   }
   return false;
  }
  var showMessage = function () {
   $blackout.show();
   $dialog.show();
  }
  var hideMessage = function () {
   $blackout.hide();
   $dialog.hide();
   setCookie('fvpp' + settings.cookieName, 'true');
  }

  $body.append('<div id="fvpp-blackout"></div>');
  $dialog.append('<a id="fvpp-close">&#10006;</a>');
  $blackout = $('#fvpp-blackout');

  if (getCookie('fvpp' + settings.cookieName)) {
   hideMessage();
  } else {
   showMessage();
  }

  $(settings.showAgainSelector).on('click', showMessage);
  $body.on('click', '#fvpp-blackout, #fvpp-close', hideMessage);

 };

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<div id="my-welcome-message" class="poppop">
         <div id="boxes">
  <div style="top: 0px; left: 100%; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window align"> 
    
<form id="msform" method="post" action="includes/popup.php">

  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Request a callback</h2>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="required" min="3" max="15"/>
 <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required="required" min="10" />
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required"/>
 <select class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:8px;" name="type">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected>Choose the type</option>
        <option>Residential</option>
        <option>Commercial</option>
        <option>Industrial</option>
  <option>Others</option>
      </select>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="next" class="action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>

</form>
    
  </div>

  <div style="width: 1478px; font-size: 32pt; color:white; height: 602px; display: none; opacity: 0.8;" id="mask"></div>
</div>   
        </div>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$formcontent='<html>
    <head>
        <title>Message</title>
        <style type="text/css">
           body { background-color: #fff5ee;padding:20px;margin:0px auto;width:50%;border-radius:10px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
 <h2 style="color:#FAB702;text-align:center;"><img src="http://thorsignia.net/chhabra/images/logo1.png" /></h2>
        <p><strong style="color:#000000;">First Name:  </strong> '.$name.'</p>
  <p><strong style="color:#000000;">Phone1:  </strong> '.$phone.'</p>
  <p><strong style="color:#000000;">Email:  </strong> '.$email.'</p>
        <p><strong style="color:#000000;">Type:  </strong>'.$type.'</p>
  <p><strong style="color:#000000;">Message:  </strong>'.$message.'</p>
    </body>
</html>';


$recipient = "info@chhabraproperties.in";
$subject = "Call Back Enquiry";
$mailheader = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "From: $email \r\n";

if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
 
 echo "<script>
             alert('Your Message sent successfully, We will revert back to you soon, Thank you!'); 
             window.history.go(-1);
     </script>";
 
}else{
 
 echo "<script>
             alert('Something went wrong, check contact form again!!'); 
             window.history.go(-1);
     </script>";
}


 // header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

?>
```

Comment: Do you even call `$(yourSelector).firstVisitPopup(yourSettingsObject)`? Note `yourSettingsObject` would have to have a `cookieName` property.